# SSH session with AWS Instances keeps ending

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

After a some time of use, the ssh connection to the server drops (Broken pipe).

- Mosh helps a little, but still loses connection as often as the ssh connection drops
- Tried adding `Host *` and `ServerAliveInterval 20` to `~/.ssh/config`, but that didn't help either
- It doesn't seem to be the host's internet connection since I can use the web as normal when the connection is dropped.
- Connections to the web-server on the instance seem to have no issues

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-91-generic x86_64)

Comment: Add `Host *` and `ServerAliveInterval 20` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and try.

Comment: It is possible the syntax is not correct in your config file

Comment: Reduce `ServerAliveInterval`, setting it high, such as 20, will keep the client from asking the server sooner. You want it to ask the server before th connection gets dropped. Most firewall has 30 second window but Amazon, uses significantly smaller window. Try `ServerAliveInterval 5` and set `ServerAliveCountMax 3` (this is usually the default). You need to set these value on the client side, not the server side. Simply create a file `~/.ssh/config` instead of system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: Oops! looks like `ServerAliveInterval` needed to start with whitespace. Hopefully this solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Setting `~/.ssh/config` to

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 5
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

Solved it for me